# How close pipe handle in unix? (fclose() of pclose())?

Tags: c++, unix, file, posix, pipe

If I create pipe in unix this way:

```
int fds[] = {0, 0};
pipe(fds);
```

Then make `FILE *` from `fds[0]` this way:

```
FILE *pipe_read = fdopen(fds[0], "rt");
```

Then how should I close this file (`pipe_read`)?

1. `fclose(pipe_read)`
2. `pclose(pipe_read)`
3. `close(fileno(pipe_read))`

Comment: next time: `man popen` gives you the information in line 3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fdopen` returns a `FILE*` so you should `fclose` it. This will also close the underlying file descriptor as well.

The `pclose` call is meant for closing a handle created with `popen`, a function you use for running a command and connecting to it with pipes.

The `close` call will close the underlying file descriptor but, unfortunately, before the file handle has had a chance to flush its data out - in other words, you're likely to lose data.

Comment: Thanks. In my case I was usign `popen`, I used fclose.. stupid me. I needed to use `pclose()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use fclose(pipe_read).

close() closes the file descriptor in the kernel. It's not enough because the file pointer is not free. So you should use fclose() on pipe_read, which will also take care of closing the file descriptor.