# What is going on when fclose on FILE created with popen?

Tags: linux, macos, popen, fclose

I just had to track down a very annoying bug where somebody used `popen` to open a pipe but closed the C FILE with `fclose` instead of `pclose`. On Linux this was no problem, but later this program was compiled on a OSX and things got awry.

So I wonder, what is going wrong when closing a pipe created by `popen` with `fclose` instead of `pclose`? And why was this working on linux, but not OSX/BSD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might only *appear* to work with Linux, e.g., you did not notice the problem.  These questions list a few of the ways your program might malfunction (on a variety of platforms) when using `fclose` where `pclose` is needed:

- *[use fclose to pipe of popen is a serious bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318357/use-fclose-to-pipe-of-popen-is-a-serious-bug)*
- *[fclose()/pclose() may block on some file pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736983/fclose-pclose-may-block-on-some-file-pointers)*

Those have several comments regarding the bad things that can happen (e.g., [zombie processes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30891/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-zombie-process-without-reboot)) from not closing the pipe properly.  In some cases, your program may open a pipe *once*, and then fail to open a pipe a second time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of answer you imagine you could get to these questions, but…

> So I wonder, what is going wrong when closing a pipe created by `popen` with `fclose` instead of `pclose`?

What's going wrong is the programmer is not adhering to the design contract of the `popen` API. This results in undefined behavior. Exactly what behavior you get is an implementation detail. Literally, you can't know what might go wrong except by analyzing the implementation of the C library you're using.

> And why was this working on linux, but not OSX/BSD?

Because undefined behavior can include `fclose` apparently working like `pclose` on a file pointer returned by `popen`. Or it can include it not working in whatever way you observed. And because the implementations differ in innumerable ways.

Answer (score 0):

I think the safe way to do this is:

```
  if( lseek(fileno(fp), (off_t) 0, SEEK_SET) < 0 )
    pclose(fp);
  else
    fclose(fp);
```

Why the library doesn't just implement fclose this way is beyond me.